# Is the "let" keyword required when declaring the index variable in a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, let

Sorry if this is very basic. I'm new to Javascript and can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

I realized while coding that I've been omitting the *let* keyword from my for loops. But in all the documentation I've read, I always see *let* included.

For example, when I use for-loops like this, they work as intended:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

But everything I read says to structure loops like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

I've already determined that *i* isn't being initialized as a var by checking whether it was accessible outside the loop.

When I omit *let*, is the *let* implied and interpreted properly? Or maybe my IDE (VSCode) is catching my omission and fixing it for me? Or is this a bad practice and I need to explicitly declare index variables with *let*?

Comment: `let` is not implied. You are just using a global variable without it.

Comment: Depends. Do you like `i` leaking out of scope? Are you trying to write good code, or is this a *don't care* situation? JavaScript has no strong opinions, but a good JavaScript linter sure does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let variable in a JavaScript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410428/let-variable-in-a-javascript-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

The snippet uses non-strict mode, showing that in that mode:

- if you use `let` in your loop, the variable is visible only inside the loop (block scope).
- if you use `var` in your loop, the variable is visible throughout the fuction where the loop appears (function scope)
- if you don't use either, then the variable is implicitly declared at global scope.

The implicit declaration is not the best practice. Enabling strict mode by including `"use strict"` as the first statement of Javascript would have disabled implicit declaration, causing an error to be thrown thrown if you didn't include `let` or `var` in your loop. Strict mode can help avoid some bad practices in this way.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    loopWithoutLet();
    loopWithVar();
    loopWithLet();
  
    console.log(`after loopWithoutLet, i is visible at global scope: i=${i}`);
    console.log(`after loopWitVar, j is not visible at global scope: typeof(j)=${typeof(j)}`);
    console.log(`after loopWith, k is not visible at global scope: typeof(k)=${typeof(k)}`);
}

function loopWithoutLet(){
    for (i = 0 ; i < 3; i++){
      console.log("looping without let");
    }
    console.log(`without let or var, i is visible inside function even outside loop. i = ${i}`);
}

function loopWithVar(){
    for (var j = 0 ; j < 3; j++){
      console.log("looping with var");
    }
    console.log(`using var, j is visible inside function even outside loop. j = ${j}`);
}

function loopWithLet(){
    for (let k = 0 ; k < 3; k++){
      console.log("looping with let");
    }
    console.log(`using let, k is not visible inside function but outside loop. typeof(k) = ${typeof(k)}`);
}
```